# Producing multi-level dictionary from word and part-of-speech

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, part-of-speech

Given some Penn Treebank tagged text in this format:

"David/NNP Short/NNP will/MD chair/VB the/DT meeting/NN ./. The/DT boy/NN sits/VBZ on/IN the/DT chair/NN ./."

I would like to produce a multi-level dictionary that has the word as a key and counts the frequency it appears tagged as each POS so we have ['Chair, VB : 1, NN : 1', 'The, DT : 3',] etc.

I figure I can use regexes to extract the word and the corresponding POS.

```
r'[A+Za+z]+/' and r'/[A+Z]+'
```

But can't work out how to put this together to make an entry for a word and its corresponding POS occurences.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use regular expressions in this case.

What you can do is to split by space and then by slash collecting the results into a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of `defaultdict` of `int`:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: s = "David/NNP Short/NNP will/MD chair/VB the/DT meeting/NN ./. The/DT boy/NN sits/VBZ on/IN the/DT chair/NN
   ...:  ./."

In [4]: d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

In [5]: for item in s.split():
   ...:     word, tag = item.split("/")
   ...:     word = word.lower()
   ...:     d[word][tag] += 1
```

Now the `d` would be:

```
In [6]: for word, word_data in d.items():
    ...:     for tag, count in word_data.items():
    ...:         print(word, tag, count)
    ...:         
('boy', 'NN', 1)
('short', 'NNP', 1)
('on', 'IN', 1)
('david', 'NNP', 1)
('will', 'MD', 1)
('sits', 'VBZ', 1)
('chair', 'VB', 1)
('chair', 'NN', 1)
('.', '.', 2)
('meeting', 'NN', 1)
('the', 'DT', 3)
```

Comment: This looks like a great solutions - thanks! I would want this to omit punctuation so could I performed a regex afterwards to do this? Also, when performed over a file:

Comment: @user1893110 yeah, you can still though use regex to get the words and tags and then apply that defaultdict of defaultdict part. Thanks.

Comment: for line in infile:
        for token in line.split():
            word, tag = token.split("/")
            d[word][tag] += 1

I receive this error: word, tag = token.split("/")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @user1893110 have you stripped the line prior to splitting? `line = line.strip()`.

Comment: @alexce yep no luck:

Comment: @user1893110 okay, what is there inside the file? I guess not every item is delimited by `/`..

Comment: @alexce Right, I see. Where there was previously whitespace, is now replaced by a closing square bracket and an opening one for start of a new one e.g. ''to/TO', 'yield/VB', '12.78/CD', '%/NN', './.']
['Japan/NNP', "'s/POS", 'No./NN', '111/CD',

This is after I've done line.strip().split()

Comment: @alexce Have fixed this with use of regex now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126040/discussion-between-user1893110-and-alecxe).